# Convert type-level list '[a,b,c,...] to function a->b->c->

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-level-computation

I have a data family indexed by type-level list, where types in a list correspond to parameters of a data instance.
I want to write function that will have different arity and parameters depending on a data instance, so I could use it like synonym for every data instance in the family.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators, 
             TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, PolyKinds #-}

module Issue where


type family (->>) (l :: [*]) (y :: *) :: * where
    '[]       ->> y = y
    (x ': xs) ->> y = x -> (xs ->> y)

class CVal (f :: [*]) where
    data Val f :: *
    construct :: f ->> Val f

instance CVal '[Int, Float, Bool] where
    data Val '[Int, Float, Bool] = Val2 Int Float Bool
    construct = Val2
```

This compiles fine. But when I try to apply `construct` function:

```
v :: Val '[Int, Float, Bool]
v = construct 0 0 True
```

it produces error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a0
                              -> a1 -> Bool -> Val '[Int, Float, Bool]'
            with actual type `f0 ->> Val f0'
The type variables `f0', `a0', `a1' are ambiguous
The function `construct' is applied to three arguments,
but its type `f0 ->> Val f0' has none
In the expression: construct 0 0 True
In an equation for `v': v = construct 0 0 True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code fails to typecheck because [type families are not (necessarily) injective](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Injectivity.2C_type_inference.2C_and_ambiguity). If you help out GHC by specifying the choice of `f` in `f ->> Val f`, then it works as expected:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators, 
             TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, PolyKinds #-}

module Issue where

import Data.Proxy

type family (->>) (l :: [*]) (y :: *) :: * where
    '[]       ->> y = y
    (x ': xs) ->> y = x -> (xs ->> y)

class CVal (f :: [*]) where
    data Val f :: *
    construct :: proxy f -> f ->> Val f

instance CVal '[Int, Float, Bool] where
    data Val '[Int, Float, Bool] = Val2 Int Float Bool deriving Show
    construct _ = Val2

v :: Val '[Int, Float, Bool]
v = construct (Proxy :: Proxy '[Int, Float, Bool]) 0 0 True
```

The key point is passing that `Proxy :: Proxy '[Int, Float, Bool]` argument to `construct`, thereby fixing the choice of `f`. That is because there is nothing holding you back from having types `f1` and `f2` such that `f1 ->> Val f1 ~ f2 ->> Val f2`.

Don't worry, [this shortcoming of the language is being looked at](http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2015/05/injective-type-families-for-haskell/).

Comment: "There is nothing holding you back from having types `f1` and `f2` such that `f1 ->> Val f1 ~ f2 ->> Val f2`." Actually, there is: `(->>)` is closed, and `Val` is a data family (not a type family), hence injective. Unfortunately, GHC simply doesn't take advantage of the closedness of type families during any of its reasoning (yet?).